# Compress 4 character sequences into 2 bit per character file efficiently

Tags: c, bash, file-io, binary, compression

I am trying to compress a genome sequence. These are strings of the letters "A" "C" "G" and "T". In the text file form they are stored as characters. Since there are only 4 of them the can be represented as two bits in a file.

in other words: ACTG -> 00 01 10 11, instead of the 8 bit characters

This data would be written back to a file in which each byte would represent 4 characters. What is the most efficient way to do this in a bash script or a C program?

Thanks!

Comment: `char`s are the smallest datatype in C and they are still 8 bits. You can't really create a 2-bit size, but look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2500006/5021321) for some suggestions as to do create a 1 byte `struct` to hold 4 pieces of info.

Comment: couldnt you assign a number to each of the possible permutations? Of course, then you have to read/write your file in binary mode. Saving numbers as readable text won't really have much space savings. Below looks good. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, I could assign a value to each permutation of four, but im trying to figure out an efficient way to do that. Using a switch seems very time consuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a filter that encodes the sequences in least significant bits first:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned i = 0;
    int c, d = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        switch (c) {
          case 'A': d |= 0 << (2 * (i & 3)); break;
          case 'C': d |= 1 << (2 * (i & 3)); break;
          case 'T': d |= 2 << (2 * (i & 3)); break;
          case 'G': d |= 3 << (2 * (i & 3)); break;
          default: continue; // ignore all other characters
        }
        if ((++i & 3) == 0) {
            putchar(d);
            d = 0;
        }
    }
    if (i & 3) {
        putchar(d);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here is one with most significant bits first (aka pixel order)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned i = 0;
    int c, d = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        switch (c) {
          case 'A': d = (d << 2) | 0; break;
          case 'C': d = (d << 2) | 1; break;
          case 'T': d = (d << 2) | 2; break;
          case 'G': d = (d << 2) | 3; break;
          default: continue; // ignore all other characters
        }
        if ((++i & 3) == 0) {
            putchar(d);
            d = 0;
        }
    }
    if (i & 3) {
        putchar(d << (2 * (3 - (i & 3))));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- the sequence is implicitly padded with `A`s upto a multiple of 4 bases.
- writing binary data to `stdout` may produce incorrect output on systems where `stdout` is in text mode by default with different semantics than binary mode (such as Windows, unlike OS/X or Unix).

Comment: I do believe you mean `<< (2*(i & 3))` instead of `<< (i & 3)`, since each unit is two bits long. An additional note: The final byte could use the highest/lowest two bits to encode the number of characters in the final byte (0 to 3). A personal opinion: The MSB first (pixel order, second example) tends to yield faster code on typical processors (including microcontrollers), and is more common (order) in image and bit stream formats, so I'd recommend that.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: you are correct, answer updated.  The pixel order is more common, but is somewhat inconsistent: the nth base should be in byte number `n / 4` and use bits number `2 * (n%4)` and `2 * (n%4) + 1`.  This inconsistency goes all the way back to the early days of bitmap graphics where pixels were ordered in graphics memory bytes in an order visually compatible with their base two transcription in arabic numerals. This order is mathematically inconsistent but culturally correct for westerners.

Comment: I don't quite understand. The `n`th base is in byte number `n / 4` and does use bits `2 * (n%4)` and `2 * (n%4) + 1` in both your example code and in general. Oh, I see: the inconsistency is that the *order* is most significant bits first, but the *alignment* or *packing* is least significant bits (occupied) first. I don't think western habits is the reason for this (in particular, MSB labeled bit 0 on some architectures would be more westernish, but is nowadays rare); I think bit shift being ubiquitous and making packing/unpacking this form simple and fast is more likely the reason.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: numbers are written in the order in English and Arabic, but in English the most significant digit comes first, whereas in Arabic, since it is read fro right to left, the *least significant* digit comes first. As you mention in your comment, numbering bits from the most significant down is quite rare today, as is it more natural to consider bit *n* to represent the value *2^n*.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. Well, I disagree that the order in which we write numbers is particularly Western; after all, the decimal numeral system is derived from the hindu-arabic numeral system! One could argue that writing "three hundred and twenty-one" -- since in many languages that used to be said as "one and twenty and three hundred" --, as 123 would be more "western"... However, I fully agree that the orders are not mathematically based, nor optimal, and are instead arbitrarily chosen, probably for cultural reasons.